# Post data in an array using retrofit in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, retrofit, retrofit2

I am posting an array in android retrofit I have to send the data of three fields in an array but I am not understanding how to do that I am successfully getting these three fields data but I am confused how to post this in an array can any one please help me with the sample code. thanks in advance.

```
profile_base64 = {
    name : abc.jpg
    type : image/jpg
    string : 8323583475dsfsdbvcnwe
};
```

I have to post array of name `profile_base64` and then in this array I have to send the data of three fields like `name` `type` and `string`

Comment: Use Hashmap<String, Object> instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: can you please write a sample code for this ... @arpitbandil

Answer (score 0):

> API call

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("profile_base64", new Model("abc.jpg","image/jpg","8323583475dsfsdbvcnwe"));

JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        Call<RestResponse<AccessToken>> call = apiInterface.apiName((JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(gson.toJson(map)));
```

> Model.java

```
public class Model {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String string;

    public Model(String name, String type, String string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```